# Javascript Document.write Issue

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to get the lines of code below to help me write "`<?php include('like.php'); ?>`" on a page only when the visitor isn't using a a mobile device but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on how to get it to work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width > 699 {
document.write("<?php include('like.php'); ?>")
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: it doesnt work that way... you cant get javascript to write php..

Comment: you cannot write things like that, tag <$php ... $> is server side

Comment: Also, why you shouldn't use document.write: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can not have JavaScript include a piece of PHP-code and have it executed. As PHP is run server-side, before the page is served to the client, injecting the code like you suggest would just write `<?php include('like.php'); ?>` as plain text to the document.

You could however load the content of `like.php` through Ajax and inject it into the DOM, if a certain criteria is met.

With a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it is quite easy, as it provide a method [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that let you load content into the DOM like that. You could do it something like this:

```
// Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function () {
    // Check the width of the screen
    if (screen.width > 699) {
        // Load the content and add the HTML to an element
        $('#id-of-element-to-add-content-to').load('like.php');
    }
});
```

In the above example, the content of `like.php` will be loaded into the HTML-element with id `id-of-element-to-add-content-to`, but you could use any selector you like, that match your need. If you want to replace the entire body of the page, your could do `$('body').load('like.php');` instead.

More about the available jQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3):

By the time JavaScript is writing to the document, it's too late - PHP has already sent everything to the browser. Your next best approach would be to make an [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) call to fetch the content and append it to the DOM.

Assuming you're willing to use a JavaScript framework like jQuery, it's quite simple:

```
if (screen.width > 699) {
    $.ajax({
        url      : '/like.php',
        dataType : 'html',
        success  : function(data) {
            $('#myContainer').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

javascript executes on the browser and php executes on the server so, you need to add an if condition and then include

Answer (score 0):

you could test the user agent server side and append that line if not from a mobile device